# SQL- Show only users with certain awards

Tags: sql, relational-division

I have an Access user database similar to

```
UserName |
Award |
DateGiven
```

We assign various types of awards. Each award assignment would have a separate entry. I need to be able to find which users have been assigned 3 specific awards.

For instance:

We assign award a, b, c, d, e, and f.

```
john, a, 01/01/14|
bill, b, 02/02/14|
john, c, 01/02/14|
mary, a, 01/01/14|
sue, e, 01/01/14|
john, b, 01/01/14|
```

I need to be able to show which users have been assigned award a and b and c, so from the above it would only show John.

Ideas?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 4):

```
select username
from your_table
where award in ('a','b','c')
group by username
having count(distinct award) = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select username
from your_table
where award in ('a','b','c','d','e','f');
```

Comment: Can you explain that further? How does this query check for the assignment of "3 specific awards"?

Comment: This is a duplicate of another answer that was posted 5 years ago.